# handling return from function where no return type is expected in some case in java

Tags: java, function, error-handling, return-value

I had writtern a piece of code:In this code we are calling validitem function to check if passes param is some valid item or not.If it is valid item,i want to return that item else i want to abort processing stating its not valid item.Please suggest solution for the initial code writtern below, on how to handle situation where we dont want to return anything.And if we return null,then how and where to have exception catching?

```
public void constructdata(){
    String foo = validitem(param);
    //code to avoid processing if null is returned
}
public validitem(String item){
    if(item.equals("Apple"){
        return item;
    }
    if(item.equals("Ball"){
        return item;}
    return null;
}
```

Comment: if its something container.putField(key,validitem(param)) then how to write what you suggested,ie we want to do putfield only if its a not null else throw exception ,please give proper code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `validitem()` still to return null and if so, throw an exception:

```
String foo = validitem(param);
if ( foo != null ) {
    container.putField(key, foo);
} else {
    throw new Exception();
}
```

If you want to make `validitem()` only return a valid value and throw an exception otherwise:

```
public void constructdata(){
    try {
        container.putField(key, validitem(param));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Handle exception
    }
}

public validitem(String item) throws Exception {
    if (item.equals("Apple") {
        return item;
    }
    if (item.equals("Ball") {
        return item;
    }
    throw new Exception("Error message");
}
```

You should use a more specific exception than `Exception()`. I've only used it to demonstrate the logic.

Comment: if its something container.putField(key,validitem(param)) then how to write what you suggested,ie we want to do putfield only if its a not null else throw exception ,please give proper code

Answer (score 0):

Avoid returning null when possible because it can lead to bugs, insted you can return a Java8 [Optional](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html).  If you are not using java8 there is an equivalent in the [guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html) library.  Returning an Optional forces the client to think about how to handle the case where nothing is returned.